# Overflow anticipation/Timeout Mac OS X

Tags: macos, python-3.x, error-handling, timeout

I have a calculator program that can do exponent calculations, but it doesn't like (cannot process) things like 10^10000000000000. I saw a previous post that said use signal to timeout but that was only unix. Another bit about my code: when equals is pressed, it runs the input through a try block, with the exception printing ERROR to the display of the calculator. Is there any way I can detect a potential overflow and raise an error or timeout after some time has elapsed (raising an error)? Note: File needs to be transferred to another system, so the solution must be versatile. Thanks!
EDIT: I am using python to run tkinter to make the GUI below. I need to transfer the file to my raspberry pi running Jessie.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

    class Calc:
        def __init__(self,master):
            self.master = master

            self.lastbutton = ''

            self.varlist = dict()
            self.varlist = {"A":"0","B":"0","C":"0","D":"0","E":"0","F":"0","G":"0","H":"0","I":"0","J":"0"}
            self.dlist = dict()
            self.dlist = {'^':'**','sqrt(':'math.sqrt(',')cubrt':'**(1/3)',
             'sin(':'math.sin(','cos(':'math.cos(','tan(':'math.tan(',
             'arcsin(':'math.asin(','arccos(':'math.acos(','arctan(':'math.atan(',"τ":"(math.tau)",
             'π':'(math.pi)','e':'(math.e)',"e^":"math.exp(",'(π/2)':'((math.pi)/2)','(π/3)':'((math.pi)/3)','(π/4)':'((math.pi)/4)',
                          "A":"self.varlist['A']","B":"self.varlist['B']","C":"self.varlist['C']","D":"self.varlist['D']",
                          "E":"self.varlist['E']","F":"self.varlist['F']","G":"self.varlist['G']","H":"self.varlist['H']",
                          "I":"self.varlist['I']","J":"self.varlist['J']",
                          "mod(":"math.fmod(","e^(":"math.exp(","ln(":"math.log(","log(":"math.log10(","log b (":"math.log(",
                          "sec(":"(1/math.cos(","csc(":"(1/math.sin(","cot(":"(1/math.tan(","arcsec(":"(1/math.acos(","arccsc(":"(1/math.asin(","arccot(":"(1/math.atan(",
                          "toRadians(":"math.radians(","toDegrees":"math.degrees(","hypot(":"math.hypot("}


            self.text1 = StringVar(value = '1')
            self.text2 = StringVar(value = '2')
            self.text3 = StringVar(value = '3')
            self.text4 = StringVar(value = '4')
            self.text5 = StringVar(value = '5')
            self.text6 = StringVar(value = '6')
            self.text7 = StringVar(value = '7')
            self.text8 = StringVar(value = '8')
            self.text9 = StringVar(value = '9')
            self.text0 = StringVar(value = '0')
            self.acl = StringVar(value = 'Del')
            self.period = StringVar(value = '.')

            self.shft = StringVar(value = 'shft1')

            self.var1 = StringVar()
            self.var2 = StringVar()
            self.var3 = StringVar()

            self.option1 = ['^2','^3','sqrt(',')cubrt','^','mod(','ln(','log(','log b (']
            self.option2 = ['τ','π','e','e^','(π/2)','(π/3)','(π/4)','toRadians(','toDegrees(']
            self.option3 = ['sin(','cos(','tan(','arcsin(','arccos(','arctan(', 'sec(', 'csc(','cot(','arcsec(','arccsc(','arccot(','hypot(']

            self.master.title('My Calculator')

            self.displaya = Entry(master)
            self.displaya.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 6)
            self.displayb = Entry(master)
            self.displayb.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 6)
            self.displayc = Entry(master)
            self.displayc.grid(row = 2, columnspan = 6)


            self.one = Button(master, textvariable = self.text1,width = 10, command = lambda: self.display(self.text1.get()))
            self.one.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
            self.two = Button(master, textvariable = self.text2,width = 10, command = lambda: self.display(self.text2.get()))
            self.two.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
            self.three = Button(master, textvariable = self.text3, width = 10,command = lambda: self.display(self.text3.get()))
            self.three.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
            self.four = Button(master, textvariable = self.text4, width = 10,command = lambda: self.display(self.text4.get()))
            self.four.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
            self.five = Button(master, textvariable = self.text5,width = 10, command = lambda: self.display(self.text5.get()))
            self.five.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
            self.six = Button(master, textvariable = self.text6,width = 10, command = lambda: self.display(self.text6.get()))
            self.six.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
            self.seven = Button(master, textvariable = self.text7,width = 10, command = lambda: self.display(self.text7.get()))
            self.seven.grid(row = 6, column = 0)
            self.eight = Button(master, textvariable = self.text8, width = 10,command = lambda: self.display(self.text8.get()))
            self.eight.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
            self.nine = Button(master, textvariable = self.text9, width = 10,command = lambda: self.display(self.text9.get()))
            self.nine.grid(row = 6, column = 2)
            self.zero = Button(master, textvariable = self.text0, width = 10,command = lambda: self.display(self.text0.get()))
            self.zero.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
            self.result = Button(master, text = '=', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.equals())
            self.result.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
            self.ac = Button(master, textvariable = self.acl, width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.clear(self.acl.get()))
            self.ac.grid(row = 7, column = 2)
            self.plus = Button(master, text = '+', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display('+'))
            self.plus.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
            self.minus = Button(master, text = '-', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display('-'))
            self.minus.grid(row = 5, column = 3)
            self.times = Button(master, text = '*', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display('*'))
            self.times.grid(row = 6, column = 3)
            self.div = Button(master, text = '/', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display('/'))
            self.div.grid(row = 7, column = 3)
            self.per = Button(master, textvariable = self.period, width = 4, command = lambda : self.display(self.period.get()))
            self.per.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
            self.opp = Button(master, text = '(', width = 1, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display('('))
            self.opp.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
            self.clp = Button(master, text = ')', width = 1, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display(')'))
            self.clp.grid(row = 1, column = 1)



            self.update_button = Button(master, textvariable = self.shft, width = 4, command = lambda: self.update(int(self.shft.get()[4:5])))
            self.update_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
            self.store = Button(master, text = 'sto', command = lambda : self.sto(self.displayc.get()))
            self.store.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

            self.menu1 = OptionMenu(master, self.var1, *self.option1)
            self.menu1.grid(row = 4, column = 4, ipadx = 20)
            self.menu2 = OptionMenu(master, self.var2, *self.option2)
            self.menu2.grid(row = 5, column = 4, ipadx = 20)
            self.menu3 = OptionMenu(master, self.var3, *self.option3)
            self.menu3.grid(row = 6, column = 4, ipadx = 20)

            self.place1 = Button(root, text = 'Place', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display(self.var1.get()))
            self.place1.grid(row = 4, column = 5)
            self.place2 = Button(root, text = 'Place', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display(self.var2.get()))
            self.place2.grid(row = 5, column = 5)
            self.place3 = Button(root, text = 'Place', width = 10, height = 1, command = lambda : self.display(self.var3.get()))
            self.place3.grid(row = 6, column = 5)

            self.hbox = Text(master, height = 5, width = 35)
            self.hbox.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 3, column = 4, columnspan = 2)
            self.help = Button(master, text = 'Help', command = lambda : self.hlp())
            self.help.grid(row = 2, column = 0)


        def update(self, mode):
            if mode == 1:
                self.text1.set('A')
                self.text2.set('B')
                self.text3.set('C')
                self.text4.set('D')
                self.text5.set('E')
                self.text6.set('F')
                self.text7.set('G')
                self.text8.set('H')
                self.text9.set('I')
                self.text0.set('J')
                self.acl.set('AC')
                self.period.set(',')

                self.shft.set('shft2')
            else:
                self.text1.set('1')
                self.text2.set('2')
                self.text3.set('3')
                self.text4.set('4')
                self.text5.set('5')
                self.text6.set('6')
                self.text7.set('7')
                self.text8.set('8')
                self.text9.set('9')
                self.text0.set('0')
                self.acl.set('Del')
                self.period.set('.')

                self.shft.set('shft1')

        def sto(self, dis):
            disl = dis.split(',')
            var = disl[0]
            val = disl[1]
            self.varlist[var] = val
            self.displaya.delete(0,END)
            self.displaya.insert(0, self.displayb.get())
            self.displayb.delete(0,END)
            txt = val + '-->' + var
            self.displayb.insert(0, txt)
            self.displayc.delete(0,END)
            self.displayc.insert(0, round(float(val), 7))
            self.lastbutton = 'sto('

        def hlp(self):
            self.hbox.delete(1.0, END)
            sme = dict()
            sme = {"-":"+","*":"+","/":"+","B":"A","C":"A","D":"A","E":"A","F":"A","G":"A","H":"A","I":"A","J":"A",
                   "cos(":"sin(","tan(":"sin(","arcsin(":"sin(","arccos(":"sin(","arctan(":"sin(",
                   "sec(":"sin(","csc(":"sin(","cot(":"sin(","arcsec(":"sin(","arccsc(":"sin(","arccot(":"sin("}
            bh = dict()
            bh = {"+":"+, -, *, / \n Arithmetic operators (op)\n format : x op y",
                  "sin(":"sin(), cos(), etc\n Trigonometric functions (funct()) \nformat : funct(x)",
                  "A":"Variables can hold 1 value\nat a time with STO\nuse like number",
                  "^2":"Square (exponent = 2)\n format : x^2",
                  "^":"Carrot (x ^ y)\n format : x^y",
                  ")cubrt":"Cube root\n format : (x)cubrt",
                  "sqrt(":"Square root\n format : sqrt(x)",
                  "mod(":"Modulo (remainder x/y)\nformat : mod(x,y)",
                  "ln(":"Natural log\n format : ln(x)",
                  "log(":"Log base 10\n format : log(x)",
                  "log b (":"Logarithm of base b\n format : log(x,b)",
                  "sto(":"Store value to variable\n format : sto(variable,value)",
                  "hypot(":"Hypotenuse (Pythagorean theorem)\n Find hypotenuse given two sides\n format : hypot(s1,s2)"}

            helpfunct = sme[self.lastbutton] if self.lastbutton in sme.keys() else self.lastbutton
            new = bh[helpfunct] if helpfunct in bh.keys() else "No help available for this item"
            add = 'Help:' + '\n' + new
            self.hbox.insert(1.0, add)

        def display(self,e):
            self.displayc.insert(END,e)
            self.lastbutton = e

        def equals(self):

            self.displaya.delete(0,END)
            b = self.displayb.get()
            self.displaya.insert(0, b)
            self.displayb.delete(0,END)
            c = self.displayc.get()

            for key in self.dlist:
                c = c.replace(key, self.dlist[key])

            try:
                equals = round(float(eval(c)),7)
                c = c + '=' + str(equals)
                self.displayb.insert(0, c)
                self.displayc.delete(0,END)
                self.displayc.insert(0, equals)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                self.displayb.insert(0,c)
                c = 'Error: Div by Zero: '
                self.displayc.insert(0,c)
            except SyntaxError:
                self.displayb.insert(0,c)
                c = 'Error: Syntax'
                self.displayc.delete(0,END)
                self.displayc.insert(0,c)
            except IndexError:
                self.displayb.insert(0,c)
                c = 'Error: Syntax'
                self.displayc.delete(0,END)
                self.displayc.insert(0,c)
            except TypeError:
                self.displayb.insert(0,c)
                c = 'Error: Syntax'
                self.displayc.delete(0,END)
                self.displayc.insert(0,c)

            return
        def clear(self, com):
            if com == 'AC':
                if len(self.displayc.get()) == 0:
                    self.displayb.delete(0, END)
                    self.displaya.delete(0, END)
                else:
                    self.displayc.delete(0, END)
            else:
                self.displayc.delete(len(self.displayc.get())-1,END)
            return

    root = Tk()
    calc = Calc(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail in your question; e.g what language or tools are you using, what types, how you are doing your math, etc. Show your code. Without such information people can only try to help you by guesswork. Edit your question, don't add new information as comments. HTH

Comment: @CRD see my edits

Answer (score 0):

Your particular problem is the expression `10^10000000000000` (which you translate to `10**10000000000000` contains only integers and Python supports arbitrary precision integers so it is attempting to give you an answer...

However from your code it is clear you are writing a *floating-point* calculator. If you change the expression to `10.0**10000000000000.0` you will get an instant overflow exception, add in a `try:except:` and you can catch that and display a suitable result.

You will need to figure out how add the `.0`'s in your code. You should also consider what happens if your user enters, for example, `3+*4` or other rubbish. Ask yourself whether using `eval` is really the best way to implement a calculator.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I am really just trying to catch anything that makes the script run for longer than say 5 seconds and print and error statement to the display.

Comment: Any significant time taken is pretty much down to using arbitrary precision. Stick with fixed precision (I.e. standard) floating point and you'll have no need to concern yourself with implementing timeouts.